# Azure Blob Not Storing PDFs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Ok so i have the following code-- it works perfectly for storing jpgs, but does not store pdfs. Any idea why?

```
 public bool TryStoreImage(string uri, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var blob = new BlobStorage().GetCloudBlobContainer();

            var store = blob.GetBlobReference(fileName);
            store.UploadByteArray(wc.DownloadData(uri));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`

Again, every pdf i try to access gives me "pdf does not exist," even though i can see the pdf in the azure management screen. Every jpg i store however is perfectly accessible.

Comment: Please split your sample so it is clear which portion (UploadByteArray or DownloadData) is failing.

Comment: What do you mean by "pdf does not exist?" What tool is telling you that? How are you accessing the blob? Without knowing that, it's impossible to really figure it out, but I'd speculate that the lack of a content-type is a problem. Try `store.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf"`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -- its not erroring out, its just not showing.

Comment: @smarx-- going to try that now... i'm trying to access it using the filename showing up in the management portal against my cdn url (which works for every jpg filename i see in the portal)

Comment: @Micah "I'm trying to access it." With... a browser, maybe? And surely the error message isn't actually "pdf does not exist," is it? That wouldn't come from the browser, but maybe it would come from some PDF viewer tool you're using? (Adobe?) You're being very vague.

Comment: i'm trying to access it from a browser against the url it should be at on my azure cdn that is linked to the corresponding blob. is that better?

Comment: That certainly helps. You still haven't told us what the exact error message is and where it comes from. Based on your copy/paste of my comment into an answer, I'm assuming you solved your problem.

Comment: @smarx your application/pdf suggestion fixed it-- I'd like you to post it as an answer so i can give you cred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "pdf does not exist?" What tool is telling you that? How are you accessing the blob? Without knowing that, it's impossible to really figure it out, but I'd speculate that the lack of a content-type is a problem. Try `store.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf"`.

– smarx