# PDF link in HTML opens up blank page

Tags: html, pdf, browser, hyperlink

I'm sharing links to PDF files that reside in an external server.

Here is how the links look like:

```
<a href="http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//help/hc/pdfs/mobile/AndroidUsersGuide-40-en.pdf">link 1</a>
<a href="http://mywindowsazureblob.blob.core.windows.net/levelblob/files/93c9f263-fbba-4e51-9726-95884aca6f2f.pdf">link 2</a>
```

In the above sample page I made (azure domain renamed), the first link opens in Chrome's PDF viewer, the 2nd one however opens in a blank page.

What can be the reason?

Comment: The domain is not resolved. Check the DNS settings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar link renamed for privacy, the actual link resolves.

Comment: You need to provide more information then. As you have it now, the anchor tags will work just fine. Are you talking about the link opening in a new window? In that case just use `target="_SELF"`.

Comment: The default target is `_self`. So this is what my links are as you can see. Really I'd suggest you should remove your answer, it shoulda been a comment in first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure Blob Not Storing PDFs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719818/azure-blob-not-storing-pdfs)

Comment: What is the content type of the blank window? Is it `application/pdf`?

Comment: Of course not, I'm telling you the first link opens properly. The default content for Azure blob is `application/octet-stream`, which is what the content is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution.

When uploading a file to Azure blob, the Azure server isn't smart enough to set the content type of the file according to its extension/content, thus when downloaded by client it's misleading the browser.

The default Azure blob content type is `application/octet-stream`.

Check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/windowsazuredata/thread/3a9bec05-27f6-4002-89be-5126dbfd86f8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719818/azure-blob-not-storing-pdfs) for more.